# Find a clause from a visual Rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

Find a clause from this visual Rebus.

[image]

I think this time, my rebus is not too easy.

Comment: CD on but switch puzzling?

Comment: I think it's 'over', not 'on'. Other than that you are right.

Comment: @Marius is right. Keep thinking to reveal the clause.

Comment: I posted the previous comment as a bad joke. I didn't expect it to be somehow true.

Comment: @boboquack Yes, thank you for your suggestion, I have changed it now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> Discover beauty of Puzzling

---

### Thought process & explanation

I'm not sure whether this is right, but may provide a sounding board for other people:

> Disc over but; not on; Puzzling

Or:

> Discover, but not on Puzzling

If this was correct, it wouldn't be a very nice clause...

Another alternative I had in mind was:

> Disc over but; on; Puzzling = Discover button, Puzzling

But:

> The switch is flipped the wrong way.

With the O.P.'s comment that is now deleted - "How do you spell 'but'?" (which they probably shouldn't have made, or at least not yet), we get:

> Disc over b-u-t; off; Puzzling

Which is:

> Discover beauty of Puzzling (the 'of' is a little off, but that's alright)

There's still a little problem:

> To be a clause, this needs the word 'the', as in 'Discover *the* beauty of Puzzling'.

Comment: Congratulation! You have the answer.